# Solve $\int e^{\sin x}\frac{x\cos^3x-\sin x}{\cos^2x} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to solve$$\int e^{\sin x}\frac{x\cos^3x-\sin x}{\cos^2x} \mathrm{d}x$$
I tried to use integration by part, but it seems become more difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let
$$\mathcal{I}=\int e^{\sin x}\frac{x\cos^3x}{\cos^2x} \mathrm{d}x~~~,~~~\mathcal{J}=\int e^{\sin x}\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x} \mathrm{d}x$$
use integration by part we get
$$\mathcal{I}=\int e^{\sin x}\frac{x\cos^3x}{\cos^2x} \mathrm{d}x=\int xe^{\sin x}\cos x\, \mathrm{d}x=xe^{\sin x}-\int e^{\sin x}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
$$\mathcal{J}=\int e^{\sin x}\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x} \mathrm{d}x=\frac{e^{\sin x}}{\cos x}-\int e^{\sin x}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
So 
$$\int e^{\sin x}\frac{x\cos^3x-\sin x}{\cos^2x} \, \mathrm{d}x=\mathcal{I}-\mathcal{J}$$

Comment: :D That was rather quick, or rather, I'm slow at this integration stuff.

Comment: This is a perfect method! Thanks!